# Script para adicionar evento onclick em um botão html

Tags: javascript, html

O objetivo do script é acessar um botão através do seu ID e adicionar o evento onclick, onde ira disparar um função. Fiz o código mas não está funcionando.

```
<body>
<img id="botao" src="https://i0.wp.com/cfbcursos.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/100-JS.png?resize=652%2C327">


<script>
    function alertar(){
        alert(123)
    }


    document.getElementById("botao").addEventListener('click',function alertar ()
        {
    }  ); 
</script>
```

Comment: "click" precisa de uma function, assim por exemplo: `.addEventListener('click', function() { alertar() });`, ou como alertar não tem parâmetros, simplesmente `.addEventListener('click', alertar);`

Comment: Não há como passar uma função que já foi criada anteriormente? Ao invés de passar uma nova diretamente no código.

Comment: como assim? nos dois exemplo usa `alertar` que já está criada, não entedi

Comment: Perdão, não havia interpretado corretamente. Fiz aqui e deu certo! Muito obrigado

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

Verifique o código abaixo e vê se te atende.
´´´

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="myfunction()">Clique Aqui</button>
    <script>
      function myfunction() {
        window.alert("123");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Document
  
  
    Clique Aqui
    
      function myfunction() {
        window.alert("123");
      }